# addEventListener without handler

Tags: javascript

I want to set an Event on an Element without inline Events like:

```js
    let myDiv = document.querySelector("#div");
  myDiv.addEventListener("click",function({this.style.opacity = "0";})
```

```html
<div onclick="zero()"></div>
    this is code:
    
    <div id="div"></div>
```

I expected the opacity of div Element changes to 0 but in console of the browser show this error:
Uncaught error: cannot read property addEventListener of null!

Comment: `function({this<newline>.style.opacity = "0";` is not even close to valid syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some brackets and introducing an unnecessary line break:

```js
let myDiv = document.querySelector("#div");

myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.style.opacity = "0";
});
```

```html
<div id="div">Hallo</div>
```

With regard to the error you're getting it suggests that you haven't allowed the DOM to load - ie you're trying to add an event listener to an element that isn't there. Your code is in the right order in your question but it's something to be mindful of.

Comment: In such cases, shouldn't the question be closed for a typo error?

Comment: Should be throwing syntax error though. Suspect OP running code before element exists which would give error shown

Comment: True answer, but it's not the correct answer for the error message *Uncaught error: cannot read property addEventListener of null!*

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check the syntax you have written

```
let myDiv = document.querySelector("#div");

myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.style.opacity = "0";
});
<div id="div">Content</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the other answer?

Comment: At the same time two people can send the answer. May be this is the reason to have the same answer.